# Grails spring security - redirect automatically on session timeout

Tags: grails, spring-security

Using grails and spring security, I want to display the login page automatically after session timeout.

Right now, when the session times out, it remains on the page that I had left it at. On clicking any of the links, it takes me back to login page. I want the user to be automatically redirected to login page.

What is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application and how users interact with a page.

For instance, if your page is a static page and doesn't do any AJAX or Websockets then it's entirely likely that simply setting up a `setTimeout()` ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)) function to redirect after X number of minutes (where X is your session timeout). The timer would start when the page loads. You could even include this in your layout.

```
// assumes you are using the default login controller and action
window.setTimeout(function() {
  // this should poll the server and check to see if the session is valid
  // if not then it should issue the redirect (below)
  window.location.href='${createLink(controller: "login", action: "login")}'
}, (20*60*1000)); // 20 minutes
```

However, if your application uses AJAX or Websockets that becomes more complicated as users can stay on a single page and interact with it and with each interaction the timeout on the session (server side) is being reset. This would require you to manage resetting the timer on the client-side (the page they are on) each time you perform an action. Doing this in `$.ajaxStart` may work ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)).

```
var sessionTimeout = ... // leaving this implementation out as it's described above.
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  // in your click function, call clearTimeout
  window.clearTimeout(sessionTimeout);

  // then call setTimeout again to reset the timer
  sessionTimeout = window.setTimeout(...);
});
```

Websockets are an entirely different beast, but the same concept as above would apply, just when data arrives.

Without knowing more details about your application it's hard to say which is the right choice, but those are basically the choices you have and these examples should set you on the right path.

Comment: Its a grails application, using spring security to manage session time out on the server side. There must be a simpler "spring security" way of doing this

Comment: Spring security is all about server-side security. What you need here is something on the client-side. HTTP is a stateless protocol. Once the page is served up that's it. The server has no further control of state. That's why you need something in the page (client-side) to manage this. Think about it, how is the server suppose to send your user a page and end it's connection. Then later on know that your user is still sitting on that page doing nothing and send something back to it to redirect it? That's right it can't because HTTP is stateless.

Comment: Looks like the best approach is to have the frontend call the backend every so often and check if the session is still valid. Redirect if the server responds with "session not valid"

Comment: The problem with that is that every call back to the backend will reset the time on the session. So unless the timer is greater than the session timeout the user session will never end. Basically an augmentation of the first setTimeout suggestion I made.